# Navigation Link changes functionality - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I have a main view, contentView(), which houses the main code for my app. It has many buttons, lists, etc on it. I wanted to add a main menu to my app so did so using another view, StartGameScreen() and then when the Start button is pressed I use a navigation link to go between the two.

If I set the contentView() to the initial screen through my app script then it runs perfectly and don't encounter any issues whatsoever. However when I get to the screen through the Navigation link, buttons start to do different things and reset some bits of my app.

Here is a link to a screen recording, displaying the problem - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YvriqQitVGgdJHDCTbv8sw66dRDiETdh/view?usp=sharing

Does a NavigationLink change the way a view operates? Or are there any other ways of displaying this main menu, and/or contentView?

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
        Form{
            ...
            NavigationLink(destination: ContentView()){
                Text("Start Game")
            }
        }
    }
    .navigationBarTitle("New Game")
}
```

Comment: If you are in a NavigationView, and presenting a view via NavigationLink, it will automatically have a NavigationView Bar, unless you explicitly hide it. Try including .navigationBarHidden(true) modifier within the ContentView() to hide this.

Comment: Thats not what I'm trying to look at, sorry if it was unclear. I have the navigation link working and it changes the screen, however the functionality changes inside the app and different buttons do different things as compared to when the app is opened on that screen.....

Comment: Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: I will screen record the issue now

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YvriqQitVGgdJHDCTbv8sw66dRDiETdh/view?usp=sharing - Hopefully this shows the problem

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the code within ContentView() but I see that 'Dismissed All' is only printing out when within the StartGameScreen(). I would start there and look into why it's being called.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225795/discussion-between-benpomeroy9-and-nicksarno).

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)